# Is it possible to embed a github git-lfs image in a github wiki for a private repo+wiki?

Tags: git, github, gollum-wiki, git-lfs

Github allows you to [embed images](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-images-to-wikis/) in a wiki page.

The problem seems to be that for private repos, the right to access the image is determined by a transient token appended to the URL like this:

```
https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/XYZ/MyProject/master/WikiMedia/Foo.png?token=XXXXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

This URL work but only transiently; is there a more stable way?